# image file path in php

Tags: image

I am new to web development / php.

I want to show an image if the image is in root folder its ok by the following script.

`<img src='photo_1.png' alt='nayaad_logo' width='100' height='100' align='top' />`

but if I place it in a folder it is not displayed:

`<img src='/ad_photos/photo_1.png' alt='nayaad_logo' width='100' height='100' align='top' />`

how to display an image from a different folder?

Regards:

Comment: There is nothing related to php, only html.

Comment: "how to display an image from a different folder?" --- al you need is just to specify the correct path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ad_photos" folder probably isn't in your web root folder.

try this:
`<img src='ad_photos/photo_1.png' alt='nayaad_logo' width='100' height='100' align='top' />`